# Using same service with providedIn: root as singleton and providers of component with the service

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7, angular-services

I would like to know what happens if the following criteria happen.

Created a service as single-ton with providedIn property as root. So that it will be available to the application globally. At the same time, providers meta data in component or module set to the created service. Can any one tell me what is the effect on this situation?

Answer (score 0):

To get more about Singletons you need to refer to [official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services).
Answering your question its quite simple. Singletons are globals for entire application and share the same data. For example, you have a service which adds a script to the head or authentication service which holds global auth status - you need to ensure that they have only one instance across entire application.

Comment: I know singleton and services. But I have doubt on what happen if the service providedIn set to root and at the same time used in components providers array? Is there any conflict occur?

Comment: No. It will not.. As long as the service is defined as a singleton it will be initialised only once... There is a good article about Angular Dependency Injection https://medium.com/@tomastrajan/total-guide-to-angular-6-dependency-injection-providedin-vs-providers-85b7a347b59f